# Name of the song used in TMNT 2 HBO commercial

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, music-identification, advertisements

In this HBO commercial, there is a song playing in the background. It's kind of rock and dubstep fused together. I have contacted HBO through Facebook, but they couldn't reach the department who made this video. It's been more than 6 months and I couldn't get this song out of my head. I have tried with the lyrics and tried using Shazam, SoundHound apps as well. No use. Please help :(

Comment: “It's kind of rock and dubstep fused together.” That's impossible. We haven't been able to fuse genres in that way since goliaths like Limp Bizkit strode the great plains of popular music.

Comment: The lyrics are something like "bet you never had a night like this, bet you never had a night like this"

Comment: Yes you are right Paul Waite, but I never heard a song with this kind of music. I'm thinking it was originally a rock song and was fused with another song later.

Comment: Yes "valorum", that's what I have been hearing too. But there's not even a single song in the internet that has these exact lyrics.

Comment: @Nithin - I've also been trying potential misheard lyrics as well (but you've, had a knight like, etc)

Comment: You can cross out "Betcha never had a night like this" by Bo Starks. Doesn't sound similar.

Answer (score 2):

Mash up: The Ernies "Here and Now" and "Polarized" with Everything "Supernatural"  plus lyrics TBD.

This would drive me crazy, too.  I have an affinity for this kind of fusion, and the music sounds like it might be [Here and Now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0POFnH096U) by The Ernies.  A fair few commercials and soundtracks (most notably Tony
Hawk) used this and [Polarized](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-MCRQKzRkk) after the release of [Meson Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ernies), though their first album was much more first wave.  Apparently Polarized was used as recently as 2018 in a video game, almost 20 years since the album was released as alt ska.

At the end of your clip, it also sounds like the intro to [Supernatural](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvpktYue6dU) by Everything (e:). Vocals do not match at all, I concede, and I can come back with more research on those lyrics.

If you're not looking for the singer, but for the song, I'd go with music from Meson Ray in particular.

**EDIT**: The music might simply be th[e DJ Fresh rem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZ36ugnRex4)ix of Tricky by Run DMC.  It was used in the  official trailer.  Especially around 1:30, it's pretty clear.

See also from s[oundtrack-movie.com](https://soundtrack-movie.com/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-2-out-of-the-shadows/)

Answer (score 1):

**It could be Night Like This.**

At the 1:50 Mark of this video you hear the "you never had a night like this". Music isn't quite the same, so maybe it was mashed with another song, or its a new arrangement for the soundtrack.

Comment: Yes Eric Chase's song is the only song that comes up close to this, could be a mashup but no sign of it anywhere.

Comment: This song doesn't sound anything like the one in the question

Comment: @Valorum Did you go to 1:50?

Comment: @BradyGilg - Yes, but it's clearly not the same singer. They're singing the same words, but this line isn't even unique to this song.

Comment: @Valorum The question isn't to identify the singer, it's to identify the song.

Comment: @BradyGilg - All this answer does is identify someone whose song contains the words "Bet you never had a night like this". As I pointed out in comments, there are [other songs that have the same lyric](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt6TLv0eyBg).